# Can the iPhone 3.0 SDK provide full access to Bluetooth devices (headsets)?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

So an iPhone can pair with a Bluetooth headset and use it to make calls (although an [iPod Touch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPod_Touch) with the 3.0 OS can not pair with a headset, go figure).

But can I write an application that can access paired Bluetooth devices and their functionality (like the microphone input from a headset)?

This would be useful in [VoIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_over_IP) applications or even multi-player games being played over Wi-Fi that could use voice chat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a compatible Bluetooth headset is paired with the device, it will be used transparently if you're using the Core Audio APIs; you do not need to add specific support for Bluetooth headsets to your application.

If you want to integrate specifically with Bluetooth devices, you will need to join the "Made for iPod" / "Works with iPhone" program, but that's still not going to let you talk to any arbitrary Bluetooth device. Compatible Bluetooth devices require a special Apple authentication chip, which usually means you'd need to build a custom device specifically for the iPhone/iPod (for example, [TomTom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TomTom)'s in-car navigation device).

Answer (score 1):

I think so, but I'm not sure.

The very high level information is here:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/program/sdk/

The documentation for the new framework is here, you might have to log into the iPhone dev program to view it, I'm not sure:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/ExternalAccessory/Reference/ExternalAccessoryFrameworkReference/ExternalAccessoryFrameworkReference.pdf

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think so.

But you still can use the microphone. If there is a headset, it will use it.

Answer (score 0):

The hardware manufacturer would have to provide you with some specs to allow you to use it.

Answer (score 0):

As Nathan said, if it's already paired you use Core Audio.

If you need more advanced stuff (more than audio) I guess you were thinking of using the GameKit Framework to connect to the bluetooth devices. In this case forget it, since Apple allows you to connect only to "other iPhones or iPod Touches"...