# IPhone SDK - Bluetooth capabilities

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

with the current version of the iPhone SDK, is it possible to establish a bluetooth connection to any other bluetooth device, or are there restrictions?

A customer wants an iPhone app to get specific data from another device via bluetooth. This device is measuring some chemical stuff and has a bluetooth interface. So the customer wants to send some data to this device, and then the device sends data back to the iPhone. Is this possible right now?

And by the way: Is it possible to offer iPhone apps to a customer other than using iTunes?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you can sign up for a special $299 developer license to do "in house" deployments outside the app store

Comment: @fuzzy  wtf are you talking about?  There's the $99 a year program that has ad hoc distribution which allows you to install the app on a few hundred (I forget the exact number) devices

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065459/how-can-an-iphone-access-another-non-iphone-device-over-wireless-or-bluetooth

Answer (score -1):

[Here you go!](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/program/sdk/accessories.html)  All I can say is have fun trying to get in.  And to get the apps on try ad hoc which is part of the $99 a year dev program

Comment: Isn't that link for creating and marketing accessories that connect via the 30-pin dock connector?  That wouldn't help in the case of a (seemingly) pre-existing Bluetooth device.

Comment: Nope, the bluetooth is included in there.  It's the only way to use bluetooth with a non iphone/itouch device.  If it's connecting to another iphone/itouch, then use gamekit