# iPhone API - Bluetooth MAC addresses of surrounding devices?

Tags: ios, macos, bluetooth

I am registered iPhone developer, but it did not help me to find answer my questions.

1. How to get iPhone Bluetooth MAC address via API?
2. Is it possible (via iPhone API) to get MAC addresses of surrounding Bluetooth devices (not only iPhones). I can not use Bonjour or GameKit, as they are both used to connect iOS devices only. I do not want to pair devices, or send data – I just need those MAC addresses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cannot via the public APIs. 
Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065459/how-can-an-iphone-access-another-non-iphone-device-over-wireless-or-bluetooth/1066375#1066375) answer might help you