# Is it possible to get the bluetoth MAC address of an IOS device OR of sourounding devices

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth

this is for evaluation purposes.

Is it possible to get the bluetooth MAC Address of an IOS device inside an app?

Or is it possible to get bluetooth MAC adresses from other bluetooth devices nearby?

I've found this question:
[iPhone API - Bluetooth MAC addresses of surrounding devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326695/iphone-api-bluetooth-mac-addresses-of-surrounding-devices) but it's from 2010, maybe something has changed?

What I want to achieve is to make sure, a user is nearby a fix installed bluetooth-dongle when he calls certain functions.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get MAC address of bluetooth low energy peripheral](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973098/get-mac-address-of-bluetooth-low-energy-peripheral)

Comment: this question dates back to 2013, but it seems that nothing has changed with reading MAC address in iOS 8 APIs - it's still unavailable