# connect non iPhone Device using bluetooth in iPhone to display data

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

Is it possible to connect non iPhone device (like Blood sugar monitoring) with the iPhone to display its data.

So my First Question is:

1.Is it possible

2.If yes can you provide some links for development or Example codes.

Thanks for any kind of help in advance...

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of the question [How can an iPhone access another non-iPhone device over wireless or bluetooth?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065459/how-can-an-iphone-access-another-non-iphone-device-over-wireless-or-bluetooth)

Comment: Thanks @Brad.. i didnt got that thread in my search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the answer of your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065459/how-can-an-iphone-access-another-non-iphone-device-over-wireless-or-bluetooth)

P.S. The link is same as it is on the comment of the answer.. But since I didnt noticed the comment and was searching for the long time. So for the ones who havent seen Brads comment in the question. I have passed the link in answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you want code or an application? Search for **Bump** on the AppStore. If you want code, I'd suggest looking at the *GameKit framework* however I don't know if you can use that to talk to other devices or not...

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine it's definitely possible. A protocol like Bluetooth or WIFI would be device-agnostic. I guess it would depend on the device that you want to interface with your iPhone. Do you have a device in mind?

Comment: I have already said dat in the question itself... something like `Blood sugar monitoring`

Comment: Sorry, I meant a specific device so we could see what kind of interface you'd be dealing with. I take it not all blood sugar monitoring devices have Bluetooth or WiFi, right?

Comment: yes but i m talking about the device that are having bluetooth