# Any external device for PC-iPhone connection via Bluetooth

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, mfi

Is there any external device for Windows based PC which is registered to MFi (Made for iPhone) and can connect iPhone-PC via Bluetooth.
If its there please help me with the link, also am I able to communicate from iPhone to PC via that device (i.e can I get that PC in list of devices in `GKPeerPicker` class). I have gone through [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065459/how-can-an-iphone-access-another-non-iphone-device-over-wireless-or-bluetooth). I just need that device that can do this.Is there any such in market....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with an MFi complaint Bluetooth development kit , connect it to the PC and use. See [this link](http://www.csr.com/products/34/made-for-ipod-ipad-and-iphone-mfi) for one such kit.

But you will need to sign up for the MFi to get access to this kit.