# NXT 2.0 iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, bluetooth

well its saturday night at my place and i was thinking of an app that could control the nxt. Well the iPhone connects with the nxt via bluetooth and sends signals via bluetooth. Now is my problem i found a tutorial on how to connect to other bluetooth devices, but none of them says how the iPhone can send commands to the device or how to receive/read them and show the user the commands it receives. So my question is: is the iPhone capable of this? can it send signals and commands over bluetooth? if yes how ?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can an iPhone access another non-iPhone device over wireless or bluetooth?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065459/how-can-an-iphone-access-another-non-iphone-device-over-wireless-or-bluetooth)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible
You have to join the Apple Accessory program - MFi and develop as per the guidelines
More information is available after joining the program here - [MFi Program](http://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/)