# turn on bluetooth device from iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, bluetooth

in my application i'm trying to turn on a bluetooth device from the iphone. The bluetooth device is one of those you put in your ear to talk without holding the phone. I wonder if it's possible to turn on the bluetooth wirelessly from my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because the bluetooth device would have to be ON to receive the signal to turn ON.

The user manages paired bluetooth devices. If you just need input, see: [Can the iPhone 3.0 SDK provide full access to Bluetooth devices (headsets)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020640/can-the-iphone-3-0-sdk-provide-full-access-to-bluetooth-devices-headsets/1023415#1023415).